# What is "cannot resolve symbol" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I'm an inexperienced programmer and was trying to use android studio to make an app that would find the users location. However I bumped into the problem cannot resolve symbol permission utils and found some answer on what code to put in to solve that and so I did which resulted in other words being un"resolved" in the new code. If someone could explain what all this means and help me fix it I would greatly appreciate it.

Note: The unresolved symbols are: 
(in permission utils):
location_permission_denied, permission_required_toast, permission_rationale_location

(in MyLocationDemoActivity):
my_location_demo

```
package com.example.raul.gps;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

        import android.Manifest;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.widget.Toast;


        import android.Manifest;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.app.Dialog;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Utility class for access to runtime permissions.
 */
public abstract class PermissionUtils {

    /**
     * Requests the fine location permission. If a rationale with an additional explanation should
     * be shown to the user, displays a dialog that triggers the request.
     */
    public static void requestPermission(AppCompatActivity activity, int requestId,
                                         String permission, boolean finishActivity) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {
            // Display a dialog with rationale.
            PermissionUtils.RationaleDialog.newInstance(requestId, finishActivity)
                    .show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        } else {
            // Location permission has not been granted yet, request it.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission}, requestId);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the result contains a {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_GRANTED} result for a
     * permission from a runtime permissions request.
     *
     * @see android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
     */
    public static boolean isPermissionGranted(String[] grantPermissions, int[] grantResults,
                                              String permission) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grantPermissions.length; i++) {
            if (permission.equals(grantPermissions[i])) {
                return grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * A dialog that displays a permission denied message.
     */
    public static class PermissionDeniedDialog extends DialogFragment {

        private static final String ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY = "finish";

        private boolean mFinishActivity = false;

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of this dialog and optionally finishes the calling Activity
         * when the 'Ok' button is clicked.
         */
        public static PermissionDeniedDialog newInstance(boolean finishActivity) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY, finishActivity);

            PermissionDeniedDialog dialog = new PermissionDeniedDialog();
            dialog.setArguments(arguments);
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mFinishActivity = getArguments().getBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY);

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage(R.string.location_permission_denied)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            super.onDismiss(dialog);
            if (mFinishActivity) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.permission_required_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dialog that explains the use of the location permission and requests the necessary
     * permission.
     * <p>
     * The activity should implement
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback}
     * to handle permit or denial of this permission request.
     */
    public static class RationaleDialog extends DialogFragment {

        private static final String ARGUMENT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = "requestCode";

        private static final String ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY = "finish";

        private boolean mFinishActivity = false;

        /**
         * Creates a new instance of a dialog displaying the rationale for the use of the location
         * permission.
         * <p>
         * The permission is requested after clicking 'ok'.
         *
         * @param requestCode    Id of the request that is used to request the permission. It is
         *                       returned to the
         *                       {@link android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback}.
         * @param finishActivity Whether the calling Activity should be finished if the dialog is
         *                       cancelled.
         */
        public static RationaleDialog newInstance(int requestCode, boolean finishActivity) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
            arguments.putBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY, finishActivity);
            RationaleDialog dialog = new RationaleDialog();
            dialog.setArguments(arguments);
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Bundle arguments = getArguments();
            final int requestCode = arguments.getInt(ARGUMENT_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            mFinishActivity = arguments.getBoolean(ARGUMENT_FINISH_ACTIVITY);

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_rationale_location)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // After click on Ok, request the permission.
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    requestCode);
                            // Do not finish the Activity while requesting permission.
                            mFinishActivity = false;
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                    .create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            super.onDismiss(dialog);
            if (mFinishActivity) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        R.string.permission_required_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    }
}





/**
 * This demo shows how GMS Location can be used to check for changes to the users location.  The
 * "My Location" button uses GMS Location to set the blue dot representing the users location.
 * Permission for {@link android.Manifest.permission#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION} is requested at run
 * time. If the permission has not been granted, the Activity is finished with an error message.
 */
public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    /**
     * Request code for location permission request.
     *
     * @see #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    /**
     * Flag indicating whether a requested permission has been denied after returning in
     * {@link #onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])}.
     */
    private boolean mPermissionDenied = false;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        enableMyLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Enables the My Location layer if the fine location permission has been granted.
     */
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission to access the location is missing.
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            // Access to the location has been granted to the app.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
            mPermissionDenied = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        if (mPermissionDenied) {
            // Permission was not granted, display error dialog.
            showMissingPermissionError();
            mPermissionDenied = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays a dialog with error message explaining that the location permission is missing.
     */
    private void showMissingPermissionError() {
        PermissionUtils.PermissionDeniedDialog
                .newInstance(true).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

}
```